# Bootstrap 3 tabbed search box responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use `Bootstrap 3` to create a tabbed search box like the one in the demo* I provide. I would like to make it responsive for the mobile version as well.

Specifically, when you resize the widow and the `ul` reaches the end of the form, the `li` items would stack 3 by 3 at some breakpoint and then as it gets narrower all of them will be stacked.

*Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hvS43/2/

**An example can be seen here: http://library.nd.edu/

Comment: is that fixed? i am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the "Head" section of your HTML, but I'd first check to make sure the following line is in it:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

try using *col-xs-6* in the li class.... Then use @media queries to style the tabs like you want. Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to write media-query for the tabs like this eg:

```
@media (min-width:768px){
.nav-tabs>li>{width:50%;}
}
```

And write for the other view-ports, here is the bootstrap media-queries..

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```